# Why the following language satisfies the pumping lemma for cfl

Tags: pumping-lemma, context-free-language

L = {a^n b c^n| i is greater than 1 and less than 100 , n is greater than 1}

I think i misunderstood the pumping lemma for cfl.
why cant i pick a word z = a^n c b^n then break it apart to u= a^s v = a^n-s w=epsilon x=b ,y= b^n then pump it with i=0 then get a contradiction since 0 b's doesnt satisfies the language ?
I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: What formulation of the pumping lemma are you using? Sipser's statement of it in Introduction to the Theory of Computation requires that all strings _s_ in _L_ at least as long as the pumping length can be split into *five* pieces, _s = uvxyz_. You seem to be splitting into four pieces. (NB: Your _z_ is Sipser's _s_, and you're missing his _z_.)

Comment: What is the i in the definition of the language? In your factorization the c does not appear. Probably you mean x=c.

Answer (score 0):

The lemma says that **there is** a factorization that can be pumped. Not that every possible factorization can be pumped.

Your factorization would indeed lead out of the language, but there are others that do not.